# Ember group binding

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm looking for a good way to bind grouped objects and render it to the grid. Here's a grid example:

```
| League / Country  | Canada     | United States     | Brazil   |
| 1                 | John, Sam  |                   | Tim      |
| 2                 | Liam       |                   | Robert   |
| 3                 |            | James, Peter, Tom | Den      |
```

And Player's model

```
DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr(),
    country: DS.attr(),
    leagueId: DS.attr("number")
});
```

And data received from backend is:

```
[
  { name: "John", country: "Canada", leagueId: 1 },
  { name: "Sam", country: "Canada", leagueId: 1 },
  { name: "Tim", country: "Brazil", leagueId: 1 },
  { name: "Liam", country: "Canada", leagueId: 2 },
 ... 
]
```

I thought about having something following:

```
{{#each country in countries}}
    <tr>
      {{#each league in leagues}}
        <td>
          {{#each player in players}}
            {{#is player.country "==" country}}
              {{#is player.leagueId "==" league}}
                ... output player ..., e.g. {{ render 'player/card' player }}
              {{/is}}
            {{/is}}
          {{/each}}
        </td>
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

But having filtering within template does not look good. Is there a good way to move it to controller?

What is the Ember-way to output list of players into such grid, so that it nicely bound and if I change country or league - player is rendered into proper cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on your question in the comment:

> is there any way to have it [bound helper] as block? So that it's possible to do: {{#filterByCountryAndLeague... }} {{render 'player.card' player}}

The answer is yes and no. So, as a bound helper? No. See the docs [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#toc_use-with-blocks-not-supported)

> Bound helpers do not support use with Handlebars blocks or the addition of child views of any kind.

**But...** if you need to use a template to display each player's info, you can use a component instead of a bound helper.

```
App.FilteredPlayersComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  allPlayers: null, 
  forCountry: null, 
  forLeague: null,
  filteredPlayers: function(){
    var allPlayers = this.get('allPlayers');
    var forCountry = this.get('forCountry');
    var forLeague = this.get('forLeague');
    var matched = allPlayers.filterBy("country", forCountry).
                             filterBy('leagueId', forLeague);
    return matched;
 }.property('allPlayers.@each.country', 'forCountry', 'forLeague')
});
```

Then, inside your component template, you can `render` a specialized template per each player:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/filtered-players">
  {{#each player in filteredPlayers}}
    {{ render "player.card" player }}
  {{/each}}
</script>  

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="player/card">
  <b>{{player.name}}</b>
</script>
```

Working demo [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xohelu/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been stuck with bound helper for a while, but didn't look into components :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a bound helper for this as follows:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('filterByCountryAndLeague', 
  function(allPlayers, curCountry, curLeague) {
    var matched = allPlayers.filterBy("country", curCountry).
                             filterBy('leagueId', curLeague);

    return matched.mapBy('name').join(", ");
}, '@each.country', '@each.leagueId');
```

Inside the helper function, you are passing all players as well as current country and league being processed and are filtering the `allPlayers` array by the values passed in. (The `@each...` at the end makes sure that when the country/league update for the player - the info gets rerendered.)

Your template then can look something like this:

```
<table border='2'>
  {{! First row }}
  <tr>
    <td>League / Country</td>
      {{#each country in countries}}
        <td>{{country}}</td>
      {{/each}}
  </tr>

  {{! Leagues }}
  {{#each league in leagues}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{league}}</td>
      {{#each country in countries }}
        <td>
          {{ filterByCountryAndLeague model country league  }}
        </td>
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
  {{/each}}

</table>
```

Working demo [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gesoya/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Yeah, that's a better way. Quick question: is there any way to have it as block? So that it's possible to do: ```{{#filterByCountryAndLeague... }} {{render 'player.card' player}}  {{/filterByCountryAndLeague}}```