# Is it possible to filterBy multiple values in emberjs?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, filter, ember-cli

Is it possible to filterBy multiple values in emberjs?

I am trying to filter items in a table with different filtering variables and I'm having trouble doing so with more than one of those variables.

Can anyone help out? I'm ne to emberjs and eager to learn. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't pass multiple properties into the same `filterBy`, but you can `filterBy` on the same array 2 times, i.e. chain your `filterBy` calls if that makes sense.

See the following answer I recently gave ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28111670/908842)) for a working demo of what I am talking about

So, in short, if you have an array arr and you want to filter it by `country` and `name` properties for example, you would do:

```
arr.filterBy('country', countryName).filterBy('name', 'Josh')
```

You can also just use the `filter` (as opposed to `filterBy`) method and filter things any way you would like.

Comment: What if I want to filter by a state and a county selected in different dropdowns? How do I add the selected value to the method parameters?

Comment: @FutoFarai use a filter function instead of filterBy as kalman mentioned. filterBy is syntactic sugar around the filter method, if you just need to filter with one property.

Comment: I threw together a jsbin to filter by both country and state - http://emberjs.jsbin.com/beseqo/2/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thats awesome, exactly what I needed. One question, the view "select" helper, is there one for checkboxes? Do filtering but with values that you select by checkbox. Sorry for the load of questions.

Comment: Check out the following for how to use checkboxes in Ember http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#toc_use-as-checkbox

Comment: How would the checkbox input work when using non-boolean values like a string? If its possible..

Comment: Also, how can I default that when it is back to "Pick One..." to show all of them? Sorry for all the questions, I just find that you are very knowledgeable in emberjs since you are the one that always answers my questions about emberjs here in SO.

Comment: Returning to "Pick One..." now shows all of them http://emberjs.jsbin.com/beseqo/3/edit I am doing `if(country)` instead of checking for undefined...

Comment: Checkboxes are booleans - that's what they are. If you need a string - you can always display a label next to them

Comment: @KalmanHazins you have been the best help in SO so far, so can you check out this question to see if you can answer it? Im beginning to get frustrated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179679/how-to-implement-multiple-filters-with-checkboxes-in-emberjs

Comment: I get the message `TypeError: Ember.default.computed.filterBy(...).filterBy is not a function`

Answer (score 2):

I blogged a solution at http://www.emberdaily.com/2019/02/25/filter-by-multiple-values/

Essentially,

```
this.get('myProjects').filter(project => project.get('status') === 'done' || project.get('status') === 'active');
```

Comment: This filter breaks and returns nothing if one of the fields is empty (null or undefined). Is there a way to make it work?