# How to implement multiple filters with checkboxes in emberjs?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, checkbox, ember-cli

How do I implement multiple filters with checkboxes in emberjs? I would like to filter a grid table with the items that have certain properties that are checked in the template checkboxes...

For example, if I have this fixture:

```
export default employees[
{
  name: 'Ricky',
  department: 'Finance',
  departmentIsChecked: false
},
{
  name:'George',
  department:'Marketing'
  departmentIsChecked:false
},
{
  name:'Jonah',
  department: 'Finance',
  departmentIsChecked:false
}
];
```

how would I only display the checked department employees on the table?

This is what I have:

```
Ember.Controller.extend({
  filtered: function(){
    var departmentIsChecked = this.get('departmentIsChecked');

    var model = this.get('model');
    if (departmentIsChecked){
      model=model.filterBy('departmentIsChecked', true);
    }
    return model;
  }.property('departmentIsChecked')
});
```

Template:

```
{{#each employee in model}}
  {{input type='checkbox' checked=employee.departmentIsChecked}}{{employee.department}}
{{/each}}
```

jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gaqavu/10/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: I think you need to create a property for every filter. Then bind it to the input helpers and use store.filter

Comment: Might be what you need. http://blessanmathew.com/2014/08/16/ember.js-list-filtering-using-a-multiple-selection-filter-component.html

Comment: Still not able to achieve what I want

Comment: @FutoFarai - can you throw what you have into a jsbin, pls?

Comment: @KalmanHazins here http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gaqavu/10/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: How many departments do you have?  A few? Here is an ok start http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qiquxi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @KalmanHazins Thanks a lot! This helped a ton! I am really grateful for all your help

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have too many departments, you can create properties that correspond to your department names and then filter your model as follows:

```
App.EmployeesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  inFinance: false, 
  inMarketing: false,
  // ...more departments...

  filtered: function(){
    var inFinance = this.get('inFinance');
    var inMarketing = this.get('inMarketing');
    var model = this.get('model');
    var newModel = model;

    if(inFinance){
      newModel = model.filterBy('department', 'Finance');
    }
    // ... you will need to merge more depts here ...

    return newModel;
  }.property('inFinance', 'inMarketing')
});
```

Your template will look something like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="employees">
  <h3 style='padding:15px'> Filter</h3>
    {{input type='checkbox' checked=inFinance}} Finance
    {{input type='checkbox' checked=inMarketing}} Marketing

  <h2 class="sub-header" >Employees</h2>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>department</th>
        </tr>
      <tbody>
      {{#each employee in filtered}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
          <td>{{employee.department}}</td>
      {{/each}}

      </thead>
</script>
```

Partiall working solution [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qiquxi/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: What would you recommend if it where more departments?

Comment: What if I would like to display all the departments that are checked?

Comment: How about something like this? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qiquxi/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Something like that but using the checkboxes